# Crawled and Managed Properties being created in wrong Service Application

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, managed-property, content-search-web-part, crawled-property

I have a farm with 2 web applications (call them A and B). Each web application has its own dedicated search service application (call them SearchA and SearchB). Farm Patch Level is the March PU so basically this farm is SharePoint 2013 RTM. When I add site columns and a content type to web application B content (which I was assuming was being crawled by the associated search service application), the automatically crawled properties all show up in the search schema of SearchA.

I assume that the mechanism by which the properties get created just picks the 1st search service in the list (alphabetically?) and adds them there irrespective of which service application is supposed to be doing the crawl. I need to know how to move these from one service application to the other or barring that, need to know that if I created all of these manually in the correct search service app with PowerShell, that the crawls would pick up the information correctly. This is all so that I can pull specific data into a Content Search web part based on the values in those properties.

Comment: in the services connection of each Web app, can you check which search is associated with web app....central admin > application management> mananage web applications....click on the webapp and from ribbon select the service connection....if possible then shared the screen shot.

Comment: Each search service application is associated with the correct Web Application.

Comment: and only one is associated with one web app? both should not be associated with single web app, right? in each web app connection the select search is marked as default.?

Comment: What about your start addresses? How are the configured?

Comment: Waqas, each web app is associated with a different search service application. Matt, if by start addresses you mean the address to start crawling, each content source has the correct URL that matches the web app it is supposed to be crawling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by applying 2013 SP1 and/or the Sept 2014 CU. Both were applied over the weekend and now the managed properties appear in the correct web application. Must have been a config issue cured by psconfig after the update or a RTM bug that was fixed.